# Program loop in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and I am writing a simple program in Spanish that calculates the dollar conversion and if there will be any change or not (when paying). Thing is, there are two choices "si o no" with their corresponding actions. If user responds something else, it gives them an error message. But, after it finishes any of the three, I want it to ask you "Do you want to do it again?" and then restart from the beginning. Here is my code:

```
print "Buenos Dias!\n"

pregunta = raw_input ("Pagara algo en dolares? (si/no)>")

if pregunta == "si":

    total = input ("Cuanto es el total a pagar?\t")
    tasa = input ("Cuanto es la tasa de hoy?\t")
    dolares = input ("Cuanto va a pagar en dolares?\t")
    calculo = ( total - tasa*dolares)

    if calculo > 0:

        print "\nLa diferencia que debe pagar en cordobas es %.2f" % calculo

    else:

        print "\nDebe dar un cambio de %.2f" % calculo

elif pregunta == "no":

    total = input("Cuanto es el total a pagar?\t")
    paga = input ("Cuanto le entregara?\t")
    cambio = paga - total

    print "\nDebe de darle un cambio en cordobas de %.2f" % cambio

else:
    print "\nNo me diste una respuesta correcta.\n"
```

My real problem is understanding this "while" logic. I don´t want it to check for true or false statements, I just want it to restart every time it finishes any action.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `while True` statement and break it when you need :

```
while True:

  [insert your code]

  if answer=="yes":
    break
```

`True` is a boolean (equal to 1), opposite to `False` (0).  Usually the `while` statement breaks when the test condition is `False` (e.g. `2<1`).  With `while True`, the test condition is obviously always `True`, therefore the loop never breaks by itself (you have to explicitely `break` it inside the loop).

Comment: It definetely works, but what I still don´t understand is the logic behind "True". I have not specified anywhere in the code a variable True.

Comment: True==1 in python, so "while True:" is equivalent to "while 1" it is infinite loop until you break the loop.

Comment: @ASTEFANI Thanks for answering even late, I missed the comment…  I'll add a word in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`while` condition checks the statement that comes after and if the statement is `True` it will execute the block. After the execution, it will check the statement again and if it's `True` again, it will execute again, until you stop execution with `break` or the statement returns `False`

Example:

```
x = True
while x: # This will check if the x is True or not, in our case, it's True
    x = False  # We set x to False, so the code will not be executed again.
```

This code will execute once, as `x` is no more `True`.

Another example:

```
while True:  # This code block will execute forever as True is ALWAYS True. 
             # We have to use break statement to stop execution.
    do_something();  #
    if no_more:  # if we don't want to execute it anymore, it will break the execution. 
        break
    do_another(); # this code will NOT be executed if no_more is True.
                  # Because "break" statement stop execution IMMEDIATELY.
```

So what you should keep in mind is that, if you check the statement in the beginning with a `variable` rather than `True` your code block will complete the execution even if somewhere within the code block sets the variable to `False`.  But if you use `break` it will stop execution *immediately*. You can also use both (a `variable` and `break` ), depending on your taste.